How do I use the ExampleMatcher with jpa repositories?
I need to get data from the database with Jpa repository. I am trying to achieve the requirement with org.springframework.data.domain.ExampleMatcher.
I have a flag as method parameter and based on the flag value {null,0,1}. If the value is:

null then retrieve all data
0 then retrieve all data that has a specific column value set as null
1 then retreive all data that has the same specific column value set as not null

Perhaps I can do something with the PropertyValueTransformer but I cannot seem to find an example how is the withTransformer() method used?
I cannot seem to use the Example Matcher so solve this problem, any other suggestions?
Thanks in advance 
I have tried to follow their documentation but it is poorly written. Including and excluding null values seem to not help.
I just want to avoid multiple if else statements because there are 4 columns which can be set for the pagination filter.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

You may be better off with Criteria Queries which is supported in Spring JPA via  specifificatios (https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/reference/jpa/specifications.html).  This is generally the JPA approach when dealing with dynamic queries/filtering.  It would also be helpful to those wanting to answer if you were to post relevant code.

I can post the code because of contracts. Thanks for the suggestion I will look it up.
